# swipe animation in layouts: android

Tags: android, layout

I know the animation effects and how to apply them to views(layouts) for onclicklistener, ontouchlistener etc. but which event occurs when i slide the layout to left or right.

```
previousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
      @Override 
        publicvoid onClick(View v) {  
              viewFlipper.setInAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.view_transition_in_right);
               viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(MainActivity.this,R.anim.view_transition_out_right);
               viewFlipper.showPrevious();  
      }  
    });  
}
```

i dont want onclicklistener. ie)if i touch and slide the current layout to left, it should go out and next layout should be in current view.how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your activity implement the onGestureListener.

then in you activity add

```
private GestureDetector gestureScanner;
gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
```

Then overrid the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) like below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Also Finally you need to overide onFling method something like:

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        /* on scroll to the next page */
        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
                ) {
            //Ur code goes here
        }
        /* on scroll to the previous page  */
        else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY
                ) {
            //ur code goes here.
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works well for me, but not entirely. My current layout has a large amount of views in the page, and when I swipe along on top of those views it will not work. The only time swiping works correctly is if I swipe along the Title bar on top of my application. Is there a way to get this functionality for swiping over the entire screen?

Comment: I found here http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html the solution. If you are using a ViewGroup to detect a swipe you can implement onInterceptTouchEvent to get all the motion events and choose if they have to be handled by the children views or if they compose a swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fragments for sliding between views. Use FragmentActivity and Fragment(for each view).[android developers example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html)

Or you can just use this [opensource library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Answer (score 0):

You need the View pager -

[ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Very easy to implement too, you just provide an adapter in a similar way that you would with a ListView.